# Runtime error after installing a pod that uses NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I’m using extensions for `Double` and `NSNumber` for generating strings that represent prices.

```
extension NSNumber {

    internal func getPriceString(currencyCode: String? = nil, numberOfFractionDigits: Int = 2) -> String? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        numberFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode ?? Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = numberOfFractionDigits
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = numberOfFractionDigits
        return numberFormatter.string(from: self)
    }

}

extension Double {

    public func getPriceString(currencyCode: String? = nil, numberOfFractionDigits: Int = 2) -> String? {
        return NSNumber(value: self).getPriceString(currencyCode: currencyCode, numberOfFractionDigits: numberOfFractionDigits)
    }

}
```

This code works perfectly fine when it’s added to the main project. I can call the `Double` method on numbers returned by the server to get valid price strings. For example:

```
priceLabel.text = item.price.getPriceString(currencyCode: "EUR", numberOfFractionDigits: 0)
// €1,024
```

However, my goal is to move these extensions to a pod that I can use in multiple projects. And when the very same code, added to a pod, is called from the main project, I get the runtime error.

Why’s this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The project folder must be cleaned after installing/updating the pod.

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>